# Update and delete rows from an access database don't work in a windows forms app

Tags: c#, ms-access, windows-forms-designer

i create a database with access and used this database in an Windows forms app.
I can select and insert rows from the database but i can't delete and update the database.

I used the following code. The first part works, the second doesen't.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txb_Box.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txb_Teil.Text))
        {
            this.select = "SELECT * FROM Lagerhaltung WHERE BoxNr='"+ this.txb_Box.Text+"' AND Reklamation='"+this.txb_Teil+"'";
            DbCommand command2 = connection2.CreateCommand();
            command2.CommandText = this.select;
            DbDataReader reader2 = command2.ExecuteReader();

            if(!reader2.HasRows)
            {
                this.select = "INSERT INTO Lagerhaltung ( BoxNr, Reklamation, EingelagertAm, Artikelnr) VALUES ('" + this.txb_Box + "','"+this.txb_Teil.Text+"','" + this.lbl_Datum.Text + "', 'Test')";

            }
        }

"UPDATE Lagerhaltung SET AusgelagertAm='"+this.lbl_Datum.Text+"', Erledigt= True WHERE id like '"+data.id+"'";
"DELETE FROM Lagerhaltung WHERE id like '1'";
```

Can someone help me?

Best regards
JuRi-2020

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it?  Which part of this code is "the second part"?  The last two lines are just string literals, they're not being used for anything.  The only command being executed here is the `SELECT`.  It's not clear what you've attempted or in what way it doesn't work as expected, please clarify.

Comment: I used the same code for the two last strings as for the first one. I only changed the statement of the command.text.  The rows are not updatet or delete. That's why it doesn't work. It change nothing but there's no mistake also.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.  Include the exact runtime values of the actual queries you're executing.  (You should also consider using parameterized queries for more stable/secure code.)  Are the queries throwing any exceptions when you execute them?  How are you observing the results?  Insisting that "there's no mistake" is counterproductive to diagnosing the problem.  You need to do some debugging here.

Comment: Please use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: There is dangerous SQL injection going on here, always use parameterized queries. And place all SQL objects in `using` blocks, including the connection, do not cache it

Comment: The following may be helpful `ExecuteNonQuery` : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery

Comment: @user9938 Thanks, i changed that. I am a beginner in coding and using access databases . Maybe the problem isn't about the sql statements but about the settings of the database itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the mistake. I don't activate the command with

```
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

that's why nothing happened.